# fatal error: 'openssl/bio.h' file not found

Tags: openssl, thrift, libevent

I am trying to install Apache Thrift on my Mac, but am hitting an issue.
I followed the installation steps on [this page](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/os_x), but when I try to do the steps for installing `libevent`, I get the following error when running the `make` command:

> fatal error because of 'openssl/bio.h' file not found

[Screenshot of actual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cInzF.png)

I've checked the version of openSSL I'm using, and it's "0.9.8zg"

Any advice on what I should do to fix this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: If you just want to install Thrift, why not `brew install thrift` ?

Answer (score 45):

I'm on El Capitan 10.11.6 and i had the issue while installing manually the mongodb php extension.

I solved it following the indications of @user7059092 about the configure stage :

`$./configure LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib' CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include'`

Comment: thanks alot. I have been stuck on the issue for a while. You solution worked for me 

Comment: I can confirm that this works while installing thrift as well. Configuration should be done before the make.

Answer (score 19):

I've the same problem while installing Thrift like others. In my case I solve following the next Jira:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-941

> Another approach is, after "brew install openssl", to do "brew link
>   openssl --force", which installs headers to
>   **/usr/local/include/openssl.**

```
$ brew install openssl 
$ brew link openssl --force
```

> For some reason, **Homebrew's own pkg-config knows that OpenSSL is homebrewed** only once you run "**link openssl --force**":

`$ pkg-config --variable=includedir openssl`

/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/include

Answer (score 6):

I was also running into this problem when installing apache Thrift and here is how I solved it for my system setup.

My operating system is El Capitan (10.11.1) with all the latest updates installed and I used MacPorts to install openssl (version 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015). This installed openssl in `/opt/local`. In any case, try to find `bio.h` (for my case was located at `/opt/local/include/openssl/bio.h`) and you can probably tell where openssl is installed for your setup. When you are in the `libevent` folder and run:

```
./configure --help
```

you will see that

```
--includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
```

Since `PREFIX` is `/usr/local` as per instructions, I just had to create a symlink in `/usr/local/include`.

```
cd /usr/local/include
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/openssl/ openssl
```

Now `make` executes without errors.

Answer (score 3):

Are you on El Capitan? That appeared to be my issue.

Jeremy's answer on this Puma issue worked for me:

https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/718

My issue was related to Puma gem specifically, but your issue might be similar if on El Capitan.

Comment: Thank for your help,and I'm on EI Capitan,I do as Jeremy's answer,but I still can't work now, the error still out there.But I find I have no such directory like "/usr/local/opt/openssl",I only have directory like "/usr/local/openssl",but no matter which path I use, it still didn't work for me. Do you got some other solution?

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks. Specifically: `gem install puma -- --with-opt-include=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include`

Comment: @Lewis-Eric - i'd need to see more of the error log details to help. sorry. it looks like you have openssl installed, but for some reason the path isn't working.

Comment: @Lewis-Eric hopefully this is resolved by now, but if not, `brew install openssl` should get the right version of OpenSSL for you.

The specific comment that helped me was https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/718#issuecomment-139624081. Essentially, if you're using `bundle install`, it won't necessarily read the gem installed puma, so you need to set the global options for bundle/puma: `bundle config build.puma --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl`

Answer (score 1):

for installing libevent on Mac: http://macappstore.org/libevent/

takeaway for this site:

1. ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
2. brew install libevent

for the openssl error:

The cleanest method should be you tell the compiler to use MacOS's openssl by setting corresponding environment variables.

You can do that during the configure stage:

./configure CXXFLAGS='-I /usr/local/bin -L usr/local/include'

Answer (score 0):

I stole this hint from [Rasmus@netflix.dynomite.build](https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite/issues/767) and it worked as a charm for me on an unrelated work problem:

```bash
brew install openssl@1.1
OPENSSL_ROOT=$(brew --cellar openssl)/$(brew list --versions openssl | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -1)
./configure "--with-openssl=$OPENSSL_ROOT"
ln -s $OPENSSL_ROOT/include/openssl openssl
LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:$OPENSSL_ROOT/lib make
```