# 'openssl/arm_arch.h' file not found when integrating Firebase with Swift-Package-Manager

Tags: ios, firebase, swift-package-manager, boringssl

Using Swift-Package-Manager, Swift5.3.2, iOS14.4.1, XCode12.4,

I am trying to integrate Firebase into my iOS App.

I use the Swift Package Manager [for Firebase (Beta) as described here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/SwiftPackageManager.md).

After successfully integrating most packages from the Firebase selection choice (since I need most of them), I get the following error in Xcode:

`'openssl/arm_arch.h' file not found`

It seems to happen in the File `crypto.c` of the `BoringSSL` dependency added by the Firebase dependency. (see screenshot)

[image]

I know the problem has be described before (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484421/xcode-openssl-opensslconf-h-file-not-found), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726636/openssl-rsa-h-file-not-found), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676941/openssl-asn1-h-file-not-found) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165174/fatal-error-openssl-bio-h-file-not-found)). However, most of the people use Cocoapods. But in my case, I use the Swift Package Manager. So I open up this question again:

What do I need to do when Xcode said `'openssl/arm_arch.h' file not found` ?

Comment: Same issue here, seems like somethings gone wrong very recently...

Comment: Well, it turns out that time heals all wounds and [now that BoringSSL-GRPC 0.0.9 has magically appeared](https://github.com/firebase/boringSSL-SwiftPM/tags), my error went away. So just update to the latest packages and stay away from `0.0.8`...

Comment: uff yes, seems that Google made some extra loop here with the Firebase deployment for Swift Package Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as is referenced in the comments, 7.9.0 was initially a bad release for the Firebase Swift Package Manager distribution. It was fixed and the 7.9.0 repo tag updated but Xcode/SPM caching prevented the new tag from being honored for people rerunning, so we made an equivalent 7.9.1 release to definitively fix the issue.

Full details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7777